# Union of Equivalence classes is whole set: Can someone help me interpret this proof?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[Proof I'm referring to](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Equivalence_Classes_is_Whole_Set)

I can't read the math jargon, and what I can read I'm not sure I'm interpreting correctly. Beyond the first line (definition of equivalence class), I honestly don't even know what it's saying. I'm not even sure I'm understanding the first line, which reads literally "for all x in S such that x is in the equivalence class x," which is meaningless to me. My interpretation is "there exists the equivalence class [x], associated with every x in S."

Beyond that? No idea what the proof is trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "for all $x$ in S such that $x$ is ..." It's "for all $x$ in S, $x$ is ..."  It's a meaningful statement, but it's a tautology.

What the proof is saying is essentially that every $x$ is in some equivalence class, namely the one that is everything $x$ is equivalent to.  Therefore, the entire set is inside the union of equivalence classes; since any element in some equivalence class is in the overall set, the union of classes and the set must be equal.

Comment: So a qualitative interpretation is great, but I'm more interested in an explicit translation, at least at the moment. Would you take the time to translate each of the lines of the proof? I'd like to understand what they are saying.

Comment: @GeneralPancake For all $x$ in $S$: $x$ is in the $\mathcal{R}$-equivalence class of $x$.
Therefore, it is false that there is some $x\in S$ so that $x$ is not in the $\mathcal{R}$-equivalence class of $x$.
Therefore, it is false that there is some $x\in S$ so that $x$ is not in the union of all $\mathcal{R}$-equivalence classes.
Therefore, for all $x\in S$, $x$ is in the union of all $\mathcal{R}$-classes.
Therefore, $S$ is contained in the union of all $\mathcal{R}$-classes.

Comment: Also: for any $\mathcal{R}$-equivalence class $X$, $X$ is a subset of $S$.
Therefore, the union of all $\mathcal{R}$-equivalence classes is a subset of $S$.
Therefore, the union of all $\mathcal{R}$-equivalence classes is equal to $S$.